# How to make a recursive function into an iterative function？

Tags: c

I am doing some optimization about Pivots Select Exhaustive.
The code background is like this：Suppose there is a dataset with n data points`S = {xi | i = 1,2,...,n}`,and there are k pivots, marked as `P = {pj | j = 1,2,...,k}`. Each data point xi forms a vector with pivot set： `Xp = (d(x,p1),...,d(x,pk))`.
We choose the pivots based on maximizing or minimizing the sum of the Chebyshev distance for each vector Xp, and these pivots sets are what we need.
Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<sys/time.h>

// Calculate sum of distance while combining different pivots. Complexity : O( n^2 )
double SumDistance(const int k, const int n, const int dim, double* coord, int* pivots){
    double* rebuiltCoord = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * n * k);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n*k; i++){
        rebuiltCoord[i] = 0;
    }

    // Rebuild coordinates. New coordinate of one point is its distance to each pivot.
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        int ki;
        for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
            double distance = 0;
            int pivoti = pivots[ki];
            int j;
            for(j=0; j<dim; j++){
                distance += pow(coord[pivoti*dim + j] - coord[i*dim + j] ,2);
            }
            rebuiltCoord[i*k + ki] = sqrt(distance);
        }
    }

    // Calculate the sum of Chebyshev distance with rebuilt coordinates between every points
    double chebyshevSum = 0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            double chebyshev = 0;
            int ki;
            for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
                double dis = fabs(rebuiltCoord[i*k + ki] - rebuiltCoord[j*k + ki]);
                chebyshev = dis>chebyshev ? dis : chebyshev;
            }
            chebyshevSum += chebyshev;
        }
    }

    free(rebuiltCoord);

    return chebyshevSum;
}

// Recursive function Combination() : combine pivots and calculate the sum of distance while combining different pivots.
// ki  : current depth of the recursion
// k   : number of pivots
// n   : number of points
// dim : dimension of metric space
// M   : number of combinations to store
// coord  : coordinates of points
// pivots : indexes of pivots
// maxDistanceSum  : the largest M distance sum
// maxDisSumPivots : the top M pivots combinations
// minDistanceSum  : the smallest M distance sum
// minDisSumPivots : the bottom M pivots combinations
void Combination(int ki, const int k, const int n, const int dim, const int M, double* coord, int* pivots,
                 double* maxDistanceSum, int* maxDisSumPivots, double* minDistanceSum, int* minDisSumPivots){
    if(ki==k-1){
        int i;
        for(i=pivots[ki-1]+1; i<n; i++){
            pivots[ki] = i;

            // Calculate sum of distance while combining different pivots.
            double distanceSum = SumDistance(k, n, dim, coord, pivots);

            // put data at the end of array
            maxDistanceSum[M] = distanceSum;
            minDistanceSum[M] = distanceSum;
            int kj;
            for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                maxDisSumPivots[M*k + kj] = pivots[kj];
            }
            for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                minDisSumPivots[M*k + kj] = pivots[kj];
            }
            // sort
            int a;
            for(a=M; a>0; a--){
                if(maxDistanceSum[a] > maxDistanceSum[a-1]){
                    double temp = maxDistanceSum[a];
                    maxDistanceSum[a] = maxDistanceSum[a-1];
                    maxDistanceSum[a-1] = temp;
                    int kj;
                    for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                        int temp = maxDisSumPivots[a*k + kj];
                        maxDisSumPivots[a*k + kj] = maxDisSumPivots[(a-1)*k + kj];
                        maxDisSumPivots[(a-1)*k + kj] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(a=M; a>0; a--){
                if(minDistanceSum[a] < minDistanceSum[a-1]){
                    double temp = minDistanceSum[a];
                    minDistanceSum[a] = minDistanceSum[a-1];
                    minDistanceSum[a-1] = temp;
                    int kj;
                    for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                        int temp = minDisSumPivots[a*k + kj];
                        minDisSumPivots[a*k + kj] = minDisSumPivots[(a-1)*k + kj];
                        minDisSumPivots[(a-1)*k + kj] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    // Recursively call Combination() to combine pivots
    int i;
    for(i=pivots[ki-1]+1; i<n; i++) {
        pivots[ki] = i;
        Combination(ki+1, k, n, dim, M, coord, pivots, maxDistanceSum, maxDisSumPivots, minDistanceSum, minDisSumPivots);

        /** Iteration Log : pivots computed, best pivots, max distance sum, min distance sum pivots, min distance sum
        *** You can delete the logging code. **/
        if(ki==k-2){
            int kj;
            for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                printf("%d ", pivots[kj]);
            }
            putchar('\t');
            for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                printf("%d ", maxDisSumPivots[kj]);
            }
            printf("%lf\t", maxDistanceSum[0]);
            for(kj=0; kj<k; kj++){
                printf("%d ", minDisSumPivots[kj]);
            }
            printf("%lf\n", minDistanceSum[0]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    // filename : input file namespace
    char* filename = (char*)"uniformvector-2dim-5h.txt";
    if( argc==2 ) {
        filename = argv[1];
    }  else if(argc != 1) {
        printf("Usage: ./pivot <filename>\n");
        return -1;
    }
    // M : number of combinations to store
    const int M = 1000;
    // dim : dimension of metric space
    int dim;
    // n : number of points
    int n;
    // k : number of pivots
    int k;

    // Read parameter
    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if( file == NULL ) {
        printf("%s file not found.\n", filename);
        return -1;
    }
    fscanf(file, "%d", &dim);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &n);
    fscanf(file, "%d", &k);
    printf("dim = %d, n = %d, k = %d\n", dim, n, k);

    // Start timing
    struct timeval start;

    // Read Data
    double* coord = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * dim * n);
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<dim; j++){
            fscanf(file, "%lf", &coord[i*dim + j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    // maxDistanceSum : the largest M distance sum
    double* maxDistanceSum = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (M+1));
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        maxDistanceSum[i] = 0;
    }
    // maxDisSumPivots : the top M pivots combinations
    int* maxDisSumPivots = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k * (M+1));
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        int ki;
        for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
            maxDisSumPivots[i*k + ki] = 0;
        }
    }
    // minDistanceSum : the smallest M distance sum
    double* minDistanceSum = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double) * (M+1));
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        minDistanceSum[i] = __DBL_MAX__;
    }
    // minDisSumPivots : the bottom M pivots combinations
    int* minDisSumPivots = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * k * (M+1));
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        int ki;
        for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
            minDisSumPivots[i*k + ki] = 0;
        }
    }

    // temp : indexes of pivots with dummy array head
    int* temp = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * (k+1));
    temp[0] = -1;

    // Main loop. Combine different pivots with recursive function and evaluate them. Complexity : O( n^(k+2) )
    Combination(0, k, n, dim, M, coord, &temp[1], maxDistanceSum, maxDisSumPivots, minDistanceSum, minDisSumPivots);

    // End timing
    struct timeval end;
    gettimeofday (&end, NULL);
    printf("Using time : %f ms\n", (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)*1000.0+(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec)/1000.0);

    // Store the result
    FILE* out = fopen("result.txt", "w");
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        int ki;
        for(ki=0; ki<k-1; ki++){
            fprintf(out, "%d ", maxDisSumPivots[i*k + ki]);
        }
        fprintf(out, "%d\n", maxDisSumPivots[i*k + k-1]);
    }
    for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        int ki;
        for(ki=0; ki<k-1; ki++){
            fprintf(out, "%d ", minDisSumPivots[i*k + ki]);
        }
        fprintf(out, "%d\n", minDisSumPivots[i*k + k-1]);
    }
    fclose(out);

    // Log
    int ki;
    printf("max : ");
    for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
        printf("%d ", maxDisSumPivots[ki]);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", maxDistanceSum[0]);
    printf("min : ");
    for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
        printf("%d ", minDisSumPivots[ki]);
    }
    printf("%lf\n", minDistanceSum[0]);
    // for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        // int ki;
        // for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
            // printf("%d\t", maxDisSumPivots[i*k + ki]);
        // }
        // printf("%lf\n", maxDistanceSum[i]);
    // }
    // for(i=0; i<M; i++){
        // int ki;
        // for(ki=0; ki<k; ki++){
            // printf("%d\t", minDisSumPivots[i*k + ki]);
        // }
        // printf("%lf\n", minDistanceSum[i]);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Recursive code is annoying,so I wonder it can be transformed to iterative function? Also, if there is any other optimization, please let me know, thank you！

Comment: FYI -- This looks more like `C` than `C++`.  Usage of `malloc` instead of `std::vector` is a dead giveaway.

Comment: The comparison of `C`'s `malloc`/`calloc` and `free` should be against `C++` new` and `delete`. What does it have to do with `std::vector`? I would compare `std::vector  or std::array` to custom arrays. But now let's focus in the problem. Nevertheless I agree that this code is written in C. He does not use any C++ optimized containers as you say and also is using C libs like stdio, stdlib, ...

Comment: In C, recursion is essentially execution of the same code with progressively developed stack frames.  Rewriting recursive code as iterative involves maintaining progressively developing iteration frames.  Personally, and in general, I find recursion easier to write and read than iteration when recursion will do.